# Roo and Failsafe integration tests: BeanConfigurerSupport issue

Tags: maven, spring-roo, maven-failsafe-plugin, load-time-weaving, integration-testing

**case**: Roo application with integration tests autoganerated.

**need**: use PGSQL for deployment, HSQLDB for integration tests.

**choice**: spring-agent/spring-instrument & aspectjweaver in argLine in maven-failsafe-plugin configuration so as not to be coupled to a certain tomcat installation (which should have the required jars and Context configuration)

**result**:

> BeanConfigurerSupport - BeanFactory has not been set on
>   BeanConfigurerSupport: Make sure this configurer runs in a Spring
>   container. Unable to configure bean of type
>   [com.model.UserIntegrationTest]. Proceeding without injection.

I noticed that it uses classloader: WebappClassLoader

I tried also with the approach of changing the tomcat configuration and adding the required jars in it's libs but I couldn't make failsafe plugin collaborate with the remote tomcat.

Any idea?

Following are code snippets related to the issue.
The easiest way to have a SSCCE is to get a spring roo example and try to execute the *IntegrationTest roo generated as integration tests with failsafe against a hsqldb for testing and some other db for deploy.

**Part of pom.xml:**

```xml
<properties>
    ...........
    <aspectj.version>1.8.2</aspectj.version>
<properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <outxml>true</outxml>
        <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>true</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <junitArtifactName>org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit</junitArtifactName>
        <!--see: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/EBR-220-->
        <printSummary>false</printSummary>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${roo.aspect.test.files}</exclude>
            <exclude>${integration.test.files}</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6.SEC03/spring-agent-2.5.6.SEC03.jar -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.2/aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <integration-test.url>http://localhost:8080/${project.build.finalName}/</integration-test.url>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <junitArtifactName>org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit</junitArtifactName>
        <includes>
            <include>${integration.test.files}</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${roo.aspect.test.files}</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6.SEC03/spring-agent-2.5.6.SEC03.jar -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.2/aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar</argLine>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>${server.url}/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/${project.name}</path>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Part of applicationContext.xml where is defined the profile for IT:**

```xml
<beans profile="integrationTests">

     <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        id="itdataSource"> <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:ittests;shutdown=true"/> <property
        name="username" value="sa"/> <property name="password" value=""/> <property
        name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/> <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/> <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis"
        value="1800000"/> <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/> <property
        name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/> </bean>

    <!--<jdbc:embedded-database id="itdataSource" type="HSQL" />-->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitForIntegrationTests" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="itdataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

After updating the aspectj-maven-plugin to 1.7, instead of the messages I posted initially, I'm getting

```
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
    C:\Users\ckorakidis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-aspects-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar!org\springframework\mock\staticmock\AbstractMethodMockingControl.class:167

.......

[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.mbplc.cborms.db.UserRepository [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
C:\workspace\poc\com\db\UserRepository_Roo_Jpa_Repository.aj:16

.....

[AppClassLoader@3972aa3f] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
2014-09-16 23:35:33,389 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport - BeanFactory has not been set on BeanConfigurerSupport: Make sure this configurer runs in a Spring container. Unable to configure bean of type [com.model.UserIntegrationTest]. Proceeding without injection.

......

    classloader: WebappClassLoader
  context: /poc
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@65450f1f]

    excludeUnlistedClasses: false
    JTA datasource: null
    Non JTA datasource: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@70a3b90
    Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
```

Comment: Please post code and configurations to make the issue reproduceable, ideally provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar problem when I try to use *Spring profiles* in a Roo project.

If you really need to run test with other DB config, What about to use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) isntead?

By example:

1. Modify you `applicationContext.xml` to create `BasicDataSource` using `database.properties` values (and remove the profile tag)
2. Declare two maven profiles on `pom.xml`: one for test and another with final DB configuration.
3. [Configure `resources` tag on `pom.xml`  to filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) `database.properties`
4. Modify `database.properties` and set values to pom properties

This way, you can run integration test with HSQLB using the test profile and the other profile to package/run your application with the real DB without use *Spring profiles*.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jmvivo, thanks for the response.
I'm aware of that approach and that's going to be my final approach if the spring profiles won't work. I think it's better to keep pom clean of this stuff but I could be wrong though, I can't tell which is better at the moment.
For the time being I have issues with configuring aspectj correctly and use it in "mvn verify".
I updated some of the dependencies (as you can see above) roo added, in order to use the failsafe plugin. This caused issues with aspectj (see my last output)

Comment: On your output I can see some aspecj warning (but not errors). At the end, there is the same Spring initialization exception `BeanFactory has not been set on BeanConfigurerSupport`. That is why test fails (it can't inject DOD services to run test). Applying my proposal you just have to execute `mvn -Pverify verify` and `mvn clean tomcat:run` to execute.

Comment: So I'm not sure why changing the way of creating the datasources would change the result.
I tried with that approach and have the same issue of the BeanConfigurerSupport. It looks more like an aspectj-related issue than a db-configuration one though..

Comment: The problem is in spring context initialization (no aspectj there). The easy way to prove it: remove the `beans` tags and left just the standard configuration (backup the DB before ;) ). Then run the integration test. I'm sure that this will work.

Comment: I removed the beans tags when I removed the spring profiles. I use spring 4.0 and the applicationContext.xml starts as following:

Comment: `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">`

Comment: I got rid of the issues by removing the `<context:load-time-weaver />` and the argLine param from the surefire and failsfe plugins and also removing the `aspectj-maven-plugin`. After that, applying the suggested approach was successful. Embedded tomcat was used.